# Making a fade transition using JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, fade

Is there any way to make a fade animation between two JPanels? I am trying to transition the loading screen into the main menu of the game, this occurs when the loading is fully complete. But for some reason it stays black (the color of first JPanel) Here is the code I have  come up with ->

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class DisplayWindow implements Runnable{
    
    public JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    public Thread loop = new Thread(this);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->new DisplayWindow());
    }
    
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    private int transparency = 255;

    public DisplayWindow() {
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel2);
        frame.add(panel1); //Overlays panel2
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(800,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        loop.start();
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(loop != null) {
            panel1.repaint();
            panel2.repaint();
            panel1.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, transparency));
            
            if(transparency > 0) transparency--; //decrements transparency each time the loop is run
            
            try {Thread.sleep(16);} 
            catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22275584/522444) which uses a Swing Timer and CardLayout to do the transition?

Comment: I really wanted to try to make it on my own but I'll give it a try if I have no other choice =)

Comment: Please define what you mean by "make it on my own". That's what my answer does, only using Swing tools to do so.

Comment: oh I see, my bad! But could you maybe try to at least cut out the part that I require and make it into an answer?

Comment: It's not that hard to make it on your own, @HovercraftFullOfEels has pointed to a running example you could extract that by: 1) Create a JFrame with 2 panels and a button 2) Make the button do the transition from the answer he has linked in his comment above.

Comment: note: calling updateUI is utterly __wrong__! it's called after changing the ui delegate, nothing else

Comment: btw: please edit the code and format it properly - in particular, the excessive and unneeded vertical whitespace makes it hard to read. Also make sure it's really a [mcve] (no external references, nothing unrelated to the problem)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels (I know this question is quite old but I edited it because I cant ask anymore questions) but I made this into an MRE but it is really easy to answer it. Is there anything you could recommend I do? (I'm asking you because I you are a trusted user :>)

Comment: I've done this before, let me see if it is in an answer to a previous question. First and most obvious though is to get rid of any while loops and changing of Swing state from within non-EDT background threads, and instead use a Swing Timer.

Comment: I think that I created images and then swapped them using a CardLayout, but again, let me look....

Comment: Yes, I found them. Please check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22275584/) as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70622613/) for possible ideas. Also, [Gilbert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70626298/) as well as MadProgrammer's answers (always with great advice) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20347600/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52883348/), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34123681/)

Comment: Yes thank you, really appreciate it btw [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22275435/cardlayout-showing-two-panels-flashing/22275584#22275584) was in the [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76075301/making-a-fade-transition-using-jpanels?noredirect=1#comment134167530_76075301) :> but anyways @HovercraftFullOfEels do you have any idea what in my part I can do of this specific question to get my question ban lifted because as I learned more, I don't feel like I face this problem. however deleting it is not gonna cut it for me. Would really appreciate your advice.

Comment: Never delete any questions to get out of a Q-ban as that may be even worse than not deleting one. The algorithm used is not known to us mortals, and I don't even think that the moderators know the algorithm. I do know that from what I've read in meta, that it looks to be outdated, that reception to old questions may count the same as to new questions, which doesn't seem right to me. I suggest continuing to make positive contributions to the site in tangible ways (comments don't count), and when you're allowed to ask another question, make it one for the ages.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I've made quite a few positive contributions ;) few [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21252090/grinding-for-reputation?tab=activity&sort=revisions&page=2), few [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21252090/grinding-for-reputation?tab=answers) and some [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21252090/grinding-for-reputation?tab=activity&sort=comments) that have helped!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels could you please (only if you dont mind) help me solve [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/210439/strange-issue-with-using-opengl-for-java2d) issue. I can't ask a new question on SO but Game Development Stack Exchange isnt that popular :/