# Updating JPanel while on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am working on a sidebar for an application, this sidebar only extends if it has been pressed. I am using a Thread loop to update the size of the JPanel but for some reason the JFrame doesn't update the size of the it. The `MouseListener` works, and the loop works too, but it still does'nt seem to update.

Heres the code :-

```
public class DisplayHandler implements Runnable{
    
    Thread thread;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->new DisplayHandler());
    }
    
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    JPanel westData = new JPanel();
    
    boolean startExtending = false;
    int westDataW = 100;
    
    private DisplayHandler() {
        
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(1280, 720);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        
        onStart();
        
        f.setVisible(true);
        
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    private void onStart() {
        
        Color sideBar = new Color(0,0,0,50);
        
        westData.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(westDataW,720));
        westData.setBackground(sideBar);
        westData.setFocusable(true);
        westData.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                startExtending = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                startExtending = false;
            }
            
        });
        
        f.add(westData, BorderLayout.WEST);
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(thread!=null) {
            
            if(startExtending) {
                if(westDataW<300) {
                    westData.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(westDataW, 720));
                    westDataW++;
                }
            }
            if(!startExtending) {
                if(westDataW>100) {
                    westData.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(westDataW, 720));
                    westDataW--;
                }
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code ignores Swing threading rules by trying to make mutational changers to the GUI off of the Swing event thread, the EDT. Better to use a Swing Timer. Also, after re-sizing, you may need to call `pack()` or at least revalidate/repaint.

Comment: The way I've seen a sliding `JPanel` done before is to create an image of the `JPanel` and use a Swing `Timer` to show more and more parts of the image.  When the image is fully shown, stop the animation and display the `JPanel`.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Comment: You should never ignore interrupts.  However, if you take the above comments’ advice and use a javax.swing.Timer (*not* java.util.Timer!), you won’t have to worry about interrupts at all.

Comment: You were already given the recommendation to use a Swing Timer in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76075301/). Why are you asking questions but then ignoring recommendations given?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels using the `pack()` method resizes the JFrame, and both revalidate and repaint don't make a change, also I felt like this problem was caused by something else, but I will try the Swing Timer ASAP

Comment: I found the method `resize` in JPanel, it seems to work but is it practical?